# Integral of$\frac{ \sec^2{x}\tan{x}}{\sec^2{x}+\tan{x}}$

Tags: integration

In one my text books, I saw this below integral.
Integral of $$\frac{ \sec^2{x}\tan{x}}{\sec^2{x}+\tan{x}}$$

I tried by substitution using $\tan(x) $as below.

[image: attempt of the problem]

But finally if I substitute previous 2 substitutions it is becoming complex with Inverse $\tan$ functions.

Is there any easy method to solve this?

Comment: @egreg,Simon,Nimu : Yes, i agree with below all answers, Mine and all these are coming to same final answer. But book answer shows like this (1/4)*Log(2*tan^2(x) +1) - which is not same as our answer.There should be some other way to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

If you substitute $x=\arctan t$, then the integral becomes
$$
\int\frac{t(1+t^2)}{1+t+t^2}\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt=\int\frac{t}{1+t+t^2}\,dt
=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2t+1-1}{1+t+t^2}\,dt
$$
Thus this splits into
$$
\int\frac{2t+1}{t^2+t+1}\,dt=\log(1+t+t^2)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\int\frac{1}{t^2+t+1}\,dt
$$
where the second one is done via a well-known technique.

Comment: @peterag Added, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
This should be your final answer 
I can't see what you wrote too small
[image]

Answer (score 1):

substituting$ z=\tan x$

$\int \frac{z}{z^2+z+1}dz
=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2z+1-1}{z^2+z+1}dz
=\frac{1}{2}\int [ \frac{2z+1}{z^2+z+1}- \frac{1}{(z+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4})}]dz
=\frac{1}{2}\ln (z^2+z+1)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}tan^{-1}\frac{2z+1}{\sqrt3}$